# bash redirect to file if file does not exist

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, io-redirection, cat

I have this bash code:

```
  if [[ ! -f "$HOME/.oresoftware/package.json" ]]; then
       cat "node_modules/@oresoftware/package.json" > "$HOME/.oresoftware/package.json";
    fi
```

but is there a way to only redirect to a file if it doesn't exist in just one line of code? something like this:

```
   cat "node_modules/@oresoftware/package.json" ?> "$HOME/.oresoftware/package.json";
```

that would be fun I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the `noclobber` option, bash will refuse to overwrite an existing file:

```
$ set -C    # or set -o noclobber
$ touch foo
$ cat bar > foo
bash: foo: cannot overwrite existing file
```

So:

```
set -C
cat "node_modules/@oresoftware/package.json" > "$HOME/.oresoftware/package.json"
```

If you want to ignore the exit status, you can add a `!` before the `cat` command

```
set -C; ! cat "node_modules/@oresoftware/package.json" > "$HOME/.oresoftware/package.json"
```